# Print values inside a hash with symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a hash:

```
[{:count=>274, :label=>"Minas Gerais"}, {:count=>300, :label=>"São Paulo"}, {:count=>73, :label=>"Rio de Janeiro"}, {:count=>11, :label=>"Espírito Santo"}, {:count=>41, :label=>"Paraná"}, {:count=>70, :label=>"Santa Catarina"}, {:count=>81, :label=>"Rio Grande do Sul"}, {:count=>23, :label=>"Bahia"}, {:count=>3, :label=>"Alagoas"}, {:count=>8, :label=>"Amazonas"}, {:count=>1, :label=>"Amapá"}, {:count=>24, :label=>"Ceará"}, {:count=>62, :label=>"Distrito Federal"}, {:count=>35, :label=>"Goiás"}, {:count=>2, :label=>"Maranhão"}, {:count=>7, :label=>"Mato Grosso do Sul"}, {:count=>6, :label=>"Mato Grosso"}, {:count=>11, :label=>"Pará"}, {:count=>11, :label=>"Paraíba"}, {:count=>29, :label=>"Pernambuco"}, {:count=>1, :label=>"Piauí"}, {:count=>6, :label=>"Rio Grande do Norte"}, {:count=>1, :label=>"Roraima"}, {:count=>4, :label=>"Sergipe"}, {:count=>2, :label=>"Tocantins"}]
```

I need to access these values and to make some calculates.
I'm using a iteration to acess each array in hash, like this:

```
<% region.each do |key| %>
  <%= key %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

result:

```
 ....
 {:count=>11, :label=>"Espírito Santo"} 
 {:count=>41, :label=>"Paraná"}
 {:count=>70, :label=>"Santa Catarina"}
 ....
```

Inside this do, I want get each count and each label, so I tried this:

```
<% region.each do |key| %>
  <%= key[0] %>
  <%= key[1] %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

Isn't working, not appears, I search but I can't find any example like that.

Comment: Use `key[:count]` and `key[:label]` to get what you are looking for! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
<% region.each do |item| %>
  <%= item[:count] %>
  <%= item[:label] %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

It's not actually a `key`, it's an object or item of array.

Comment: Accept would be great return=)

Comment: I will, I need wait some minutes, don't worry =]

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
region = [{:count=>274, :label=>"Minas Gerais"}, {:count=>300, :label=>"São Paulo"}, {:count=>73, :label=>"Rio de Janeiro"}, {:count=>11, :label=>"Espírito Santo"}, {:count=>41, :label=>"Paraná"}, {:count=>70, :label=>"Santa Catarina"}, {:count=>81, :label=>"Rio Grande do Sul"}, {:count=>23, :label=>"Bahia"}, {:count=>3, :label=>"Alagoas"}, {:count=>8, :label=>"Amazonas"}, {:count=>1, :label=>"Amapá"}, {:count=>24, :label=>"Ceará"}, {:count=>62, :label=>"Distrito Federal"}, {:count=>35, :label=>"Goiás"}, {:count=>2, :label=>"Maranhão"}, {:count=>7, :label=>"Mato Grosso do Sul"}, {:count=>6, :label=>"Mato Grosso"}, {:count=>11, :label=>"Pará"}, {:count=>11, :label=>"Paraíba"}, {:count=>29, :label=>"Pernambuco"}, {:count=>1, :label=>"Piauí"}, {:count=>6, :label=>"Rio Grande do Norte"}, {:count=>1, :label=>"Roraima"}, {:count=>4, :label=>"Sergipe"}, {:count=>2, :label=>"Tocantins"}] 

<% region.each do |hash| %>
  <%= hash[:count] %><br>
  <%= hash[:label] %>
<% end %>
```